# CakePHP - Retrieving a list of options from another table, to use with form helper/ before Instering

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

Here is Yet another cakePHP question! I have table called blood_groups which has  blood_group_id and group fields.. Then I have another table called donors, which has several fields such as name, surname etc. Another field included inside this table is the foreign key 'blood_group_id' which will need to map to the blood_group table on retrieval. in the donor registration view, i want to be able to retrieve the values from the blood_groups table, and display them using the formHelper (with their respective id's).

I have gone through CAKE doc, and I understand that I would need to create the association between my models, but I am struggling to figure this one out. Should I create $hasOne association inside the Donor Model (considering that the Donor table has the fk of the other table). And how would I go about retrieving the options of blood_groups from the blood_groups Model?

Should It work like this?(and are any other prerequisites involved?) :
In my DonorController -

> $this->set('blood_groups', $this->Donor->Blood_Group->find('all'));

in Views/Donor/add.ctp

> echo $this->Form->input('blood_group_id');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing data through associations is fine. But for radios or checkboxes you want to do a find('list). Your model and variable name does not match [the CakePHP convention](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html), there should be no underscore.

Properly named this should be already enough to populate the input.

```
// controller
$this->set('bloodGroups', $this->Donor->BloodGroup->find('list'));
// view
echo $this->Form->input('blood_group_id');
```

If you don't follow the conventions for some reason:

```
echo $this->Form->input('blood_group_id', array(
    'options' => $bloodGroups
));
```

See:

- [Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)
- [The Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Comment: First of, thanks for your reply! Ok, is there a cakePHP cheat sheet which describes the naming conventions? Also should I set a $hasOne association in the DonorModel ?(event though the FK is inside the Donor table and not in the blood_groups table, as suggested in cakePHP doc) 
Thanks!

Comment: Donor hasOne BloodGroup is correct so Donor should have a field blood_group_id.

The conventions, as virtually everything else can be found in the documentation, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: I've added two links to the answer you can check out as well, the documentation contains a lot of examples as well.

Comment: Again, thank you for being most helpful, would upvote answer again if I could. Also some clarification about the statement:

`$this->set('bloodGroups', $this->Donor->BloodGroup->find('list'));`

Should I do this in the beforeFilter() method?

Comment: No, it's a waste of resources there. You would do the query on *every* single page of that controller then. I would do it in every action that needs the list. If really all or most actions need it I would still have a list of actions to in- or exclude the call in the beforeFilter(). A better place would be the beforeRender() callback as well. Because the script can get interrupted by a redirect or exceptions and you've made the query again for nothing in the beforeFilter().

Comment: oh right, then the best place would be to add it in the add() action! I will look into the beforeRender() callback aswell then. Really can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

```
Create one function in BloodGroup Model
function getDonors(){
  $options = array(
       // 'conditions' => array('Donor.blood_group_id'=>$id),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'Donor',  
                'table' => 'donors',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Donor.blood_group_id = BloodGroup.blood_group_id',
                ),
            )
          ),              
        'fields' => array('Donor.name','Donor.surname','Donor.blood_group_id',
                         'BloodGroup.blood_group_id')
    );
   $returnData = $this->find('all',$options);
   return $returnData;
}
```

Now from controller call this function

```
 App::import('model','BloodGroup');
 $BloodGroup = new BloodGroup;
 $donorList = $BloodGroup->getDonors();
 $this->set('donorList',$donorList);
```

In view file you will get list of donors in `$donorList.`

Comment: this code looks very interesting. However I want to register a donor, and not retrieve a donor by blood_group. If im proficient enough in understanding code, this is getting donors by blood group, when a certain blood_group_id is specified, right?

Comment: I have made one edit, now it gives you list of all the donors, pls update ur question for inserting question

Comment: Code looks the best interesting in terms of that it is *wrong* and encourages *bad* practice. I'm to lazy to explain it again here, but there are at least 3 things wrong. A few keywords: Testing, SoC, best practice, model instantiation, aliasing, import vs uses.

Comment: Can you explain me why it is Bad practice in two lines?

Comment: See the keywords and think about them. This is nothing that can be explained in two lines, I could write a blog post about it if I would want to go into details.

Comment: Yes..You can't explain it..but why it is still there in cakePHP documentation if it is a bad practice. see http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find

Comment: This is *NOT* the official documentation, this is no documentation at all. Pay attention to the pages you visit. The bakery: These are random, *not* reviewed articles written by community members, not the CakePHP developers. getDonors() is in the wrong domain and why the hell do you need to do all of that code there if the assocs solve it already? Besides your answer does not address the problem he tried to solve. My previous comment was mostly about the other four lines, but there are things wrong as well, hint: aliases. This code will break if used through an assoc with a different name.